# How prove this integral $\int_{0}^{\infty}f^{\alpha}(x)dx,\alpha>1$ is convergent

Tags: integration, convergence-divergence, improper-integrals

**Question:**

> let the function $f(x)\ge 0$,and such $$f'(x)\le\dfrac{1}{2},\forall x\ge 0$$
>   and this integral
>   $\displaystyle\int_{0}^{\infty}f(x)dx$ is convergent.

show that:

> $$\int_{0}^{\infty}f^{\alpha}(x)dx,\alpha>1$$ is convergent. And
>   $$\int_{0}^{\infty}f^{\alpha}(x)dx\le\left(\int_{0}^{\infty}f(x)dx\right)^{\frac{\alpha-1}{2}}.$$

Maybe this problem use Cauchy-Schwarz inequality to solve it
$$\int_{0}^{\infty}f^2(x)dx\int_{0}^{\infty}g^2(x)dx\ge\left(\int_{0}^{\infty}f(x)g(x)dx\right)^2$$
maybe Holder inequality also is useful for this problem.

But I can't solve this problem

Thank you for you help

Comment: Does $f^\alpha(x)=(f(x))^\alpha$?

Comment: @StellaBiderman,this is meaning

Answer (score 4):

**Answer Changed**

It is assumed that:

> - $f$ is differentiable on $ \mathbb{R}^+$
> - $f'\le M$ where $ M $ is a constant.
> - $f$ is integrable on $\mathbb{R}^+$

We assume that $f$ does not converge to $0$ at infinity and lead to a contradiction.

Let $\epsilon>0$,since $f$ is integrable on $\mathbb{R}^+$, there exist $z_1\geq 0$ such that $f(z_1)\leq \epsilon /2$.

If $f$ does not converge to $0$ at infinity. Then there exist $x_1\geq z_1$ such that $|f(x_1)|\geq \epsilon$.

> 1. $f(x_1)\geq \epsilon$

Denote $y_1=sup\{ t\in [z_1,x_1]\quad  /\quad f(t)\leq \epsilon/2\}$

The IVT implies that $y_1$ is defined, the continuity of $f$ implies that $f(y_1)=\epsilon/2$. The IVT tell us $f(t)\geq \epsilon/2$ for $t\in [y_1,x_1]$.

Once again by  the IVT, there exist $t_1\in [y_1,x_1]$ such that  $f(t_1)=\epsilon$.

Then,

$$\int_{y_1}^{x_1}f(u)du\geq  \int_{y_1}^{t_1}f(u)du \geq \frac{\epsilon}{2}(t_1-y_1)\geq \frac{\epsilon}{4M}$$

As $\frac{\epsilon}{2} = f(t_1)-f(y_1) \geq M (t_1-x_1)$

And repeat the operation by taking:

$z_2\geq x_1$ such that $f(z_2)\leq \epsilon /2$ and $x_2\geq z_2$ such that $|f(x_2)|\geq \epsilon$.

> 1. $f(x_1)\leq -\epsilon$
>      The reasoning is broadly the same as in 1.

Let $y_1=inf\{  t\in [x_1,z_1]/ f(t)\geq -\epsilon/2\}$.

We find then :

$$\int_{x_1}^{y_1}f(u)du\leq-\frac{\epsilon}{4M}$$

Therefore, $f$ is not integrable, contradiction/

Then,$\lim_{x\rightarrow \infty}f(x)=0$,

$$
\exists A / x>A \implies 0\le f(x) \le 1
$$
Thus,
$$
\forall x>A 0\le f^\alpha(x) \le f(x)
$$
for $p \ge 2$, for $p=1$ there is nothing to prove.**QED**

Comment: Thanks to @23rd the inequality you want to prove is incorrect.

Comment: @user104254 I know that, but I wasn't managed to prove the convergence for $f'\le 1/2$, so If you achieve a such proof I would like to see :)

Comment: @user104254 I hope it's okay now

Comment: @user104254 Yep, It's a typo on my part. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

The first part can be proven as follows:

*Claim:* There is an $M$ with $0\leq f(x)\leq 1$ for all $x\geq M$. Using this claim one has
$$\int_0^\infty f^\alpha(x)\ dx\leq\int_0^M f^\alpha(x)\ dx+\int_M^\infty f(x)\ dx<\infty$$
for all $\alpha>1$.

*Proof of the Claim:* Assume there is an increasing sequence $x_n\to\infty$ with $f(x_n)>1$ for all $n$. Put $n_0:=1$ and for each $k\geq 1$ choose $n_k>n_{k-1}$ such that $x_{n_k}>x_{n_{k-1}}+1$. It follows that
$$f(x)\geq{1\over2}\qquad (x_{n_k}-1\leq x\leq x_{n_k})$$
for all $k\geq1$, which is incompatible with $\int_0^\infty f(x)\ dx<\infty$.